# Are private fields needed in a class where no methods exist?

Tags: c#, oop, syntax, resharper, conventions

I've been using ReSharper to do some work on cleaning up a C# codebase. I had been using both private fields in model classes along with public properties. However, I'm finding that I can simply take the properties that have no backing fields and convert them into auto-properties. These are model classes; no methods exist within them to impact the data in the objects. Is it better to just use the auto-properties?

EDIT: Including example of "Backing fields"

```
public class Gizmo
{
    //this is what I call the "backing" field, only because it's "behind" the
    //publicly-accessible property and you access it through the property
    private Int32 _count;

    //and this is the property, of course
    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { _count = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "properties that have no backing fields"? It would have reduced confusion if you'd given an example here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it better to just use the auto-properties

If your property involve is simple `get;set`, you can just use a "auto-property". If I am not wrong, compiler will create a private backing field behind the scenes.

If in your property, you are doing some kind of validation before; say before `set` then it makes sense to use a property with a backing field (non-auto)

An example would be

```
private string name;

public string MyName {
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set {
        name = (value == null)
            ? "Anonymous" : value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Methods are irrelevant here. If you have a property of:

```
private int foo;
public int Foo
{
    get { return foo; }
    set { foo = value; }
}
```

Then it *absolutely* makes sense to turn that into:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

If any other code uses the private field, you can just change it to use the property instead.

Comment: Ok, I dare to criticise you @jon but this is not totally correct :) if you need some kind of logic in the setter (as shown in the OP's example) then you need a backing field.

Comment: @GETah: The OP doesn't *have* an example - and I specifically said *if* you have a property of (example of property with no logic). Yes, you need an explicit backing field if you have logic in the property, but there's no indication that that's the case here.

Comment: @GETah: (Admittedly I hadn't spotted the part where the OP talks about properties without a backing field - it's unclear what's going on there... it would be nice if the OP could give an example, but we may not get that now.)

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much a code-style question. So you should have a standard for model properties throughout your project or solution. If you find that the auto properties makes your intent more obvious, by all means use them--just use them *consistently*.